# SAPUI5 - Group list items without sorting ascending or descending

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using a `sap.m.List` control in my application that is supposed to show a sequential list. There is a grouping property in each list data that I can use to group similar items together.

I checked [this example](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrouping/preview) on the SAP Explored website on list grouping. It uses a `sorter` property that has `group` set to `true`. By default the sorting mode is descending.

However my list has to show the items in a predefined sequence with just similar items grouped together for ease of use. All items in a group occur at one place in the list and a particular group occurs only once. For example, I have to bind the JSON array below to a list in the same order as it is, only grouped by `Category`.

**steps.json:**

```
{
  "Steps": [
    {
      "Desc": "Open google search",
      "Category": "Google"
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Search for Apple Inc.",
      "Category": "Google"
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Open Apple website",
      "Category": "Apple"
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Search for iPhone",
      "Category": "Apple"
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Browse all iPhone models",
      "Category": "Phone"
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Choose the one you like",
      "Category": "Phone"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code below is what I would like to do in order to get going except it sorts my list in descending order.

**SAPUI5 code:**

```
<List
    items="{
                path: '/Steps',
                sorter: {
                    path: 'Category',
                    group: true
                }
            }"
    headerText="Here's what you do">
    <StandardListItem title="{Desc}" />
</List>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add an extra property to each object in the array which indicates the sort index, and then sort based on that property?

Comment: The data comes from a data source over which I may not have any control. Nevertheless, how do you mean?

Comment: Euh... use simple javascript? `for (var i=0; i<yourArray.length; i++) { yourArray[i].sort = i; }` and then set the new array back to your model

Comment: Thanks... But I don't think this would solve my problem. I still have to group the list. And doing that will sort my list implicitly. Check the code snippet that I have just added.

Comment: I understand, but you could add multiple sorters, one for the group, and one for the list (i.e. without grouping), see https://github.com/qmacro/sapui5bin/blob/master/SortingAndGrouping/TwoProperties.html for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3rd parameter of the Sorter can be a function which gets the context as a parameter.

API : https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Sorter.html

Sample : http://jsbin.com/votesatezu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

I got a way to resolve my problem. It's similar to the answer provided here but doesn't require to create a Sorter instance in the controller (so saves you from additional coding).

**XML view:**

```
<List
    items="{
                path: '/Steps',
                sorter: {
                    path: 'CategoryId',
                    group: '.grouper'
                },
                groupHeaderFactory: '.getGroupHeader'
            }"
    headerText="Here's what you do">
    <StandardListItem title="{Desc}" />
</List>
```

Instead of passing a boolean, I call a `grouper` method in the `group` property to build a custom object for `groupHeaderFactory`.

**Controller:**

```
onInit: function() {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
      "Steps": [
        {
          "Desc": "Open google search",
          "Category": "Google",
          "CategoryId": 1
        },
        {
          "Desc": "Search for Apple Inc.",
          "Category": "Google",
          "CategoryId": 1
        },
        {
          "Desc": "Open Apple website",
          "Category": "Apple",
          "CategoryId": 2
        },
        {
          "Desc": "Search for iPhone",
          "Category": "Apple",
          "CategoryId": 2
        },
        {
          "Desc": "Browse all iPhone models",
          "Category": "Phone",
          "CategoryId": 3
        },
        {
          "Desc": "Choose the one you like",
          "Category": "Phone",
          "CategoryId": 3
        }
      ]
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
}
```

**grouper():**

The oGroup object provides the complete model along with the binding path for each row. The binding path is stored in a property called `sPath`. I can get the array index from the `sPath` and then use it to get the corresponding `Category` name.

```
grouper: function(oGroup) {
    return {
        key: oGroup.oModel.oData.Steps[oGroup.sPath.split("/")[2]].Category
    };
}
```

Now when the `groupHeaderFactory` is called it has the `Category` name instead of the `CategoryId`.

**getGroupHeader():**

```
getGroupHeader: function(oGroup){
    return new sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem( {
        title: oGroup.key,
        upperCase: true
    });

}
```

[image: Output]

**Note:** Make sure you have `data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"` in your `index.html` if you want to try out this example.

Yippee!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding some implicit meta data to your json file which is a custom sort on the category.

The sapui5 list item cannot guess that you have created such a constraint on your data :) I would advice you to simply enrich your model to:

```
{
  "Steps": [
    {
      "Desc": "Open google search",
      "Category": "Google",
      "CategoryId": 1
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Search for Apple Inc.",
      "Category": "Google",
      "CategoryId": 1
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Open Apple website",
      "Category": "Apple",
      "CategoryId": 2
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Search for iPhone",
      "Category": "Apple",
      "CategoryId": 2
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Browse all iPhone models",
      "Category": "Phone",
      "CategoryId": 3
    },
    {
      "Desc": "Choose the one you like",
      "Category": "Phone",
      "CategoryId": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Then group on categoryId instead of category.

Comment: Ash, I have actually been working on this very approach over the past hour. But you know what the problem is, I have to sort on the basis of "CategoryId" but display group header as "Category" and passing two properties throws an error.

Comment: on the explored sample you linked, they use a header factory to generate the group header. I havent tried but seems to me that you can choose to display category instead of categoryId from there

Comment: I know. But as I said, it's not allowing me to pass both Category and CategoryId into the sorter.

Comment: Why would you pass both ? that field categoryId -as I described it- is only a sorted version of category :)

Comment: In the getGroupHeader method of the example, all that I get inside is an object with the CategoryId value exactly like this: {key: 1}. How do I get the corr. "Category" with only this information?