# Why grouping creates 2 different groups for same field value?

Tags: sapui5

I use OData direct binding to XML view:

```js
<List items="{path:'Items', sorter : {path : 'group', group : true}}">
...
</List>
```

The 'Items' content, bottom line, looks like follows:

```js
[{
    group: "1",
    value: "a"
},{
    group: "1",
    value: "b"
},{
    group: "2",
    value: "c"
},{
    group: "2",
    value: "d"
},{
    group: "1",
    value: "e"
}]
```

Strangely, I see 3 groups in my list: group "1" with 2 elements, group "2" with 2 elements and again group "1" with one last element.

What do I miss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is a duplication of the  [SAPUI5 - Group list items without sorting ascending or descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357711/sapui5-group-list-items-without-sorting-ascending-or-descending)

You have missed `groupHeaderFactory`, I have made the changes as per the requirement.

**View**

```
<List headerText="Products"          
    items="{
        path: '/items',
        sorter: {
            path: 'group',
            descending: false,
            group: true
        },
        groupHeaderFactory: '.getGroupHeader'
    }">
```

**Controller**

```
getGroupHeader: function (oGroup){
    return new sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem({
        title: oGroup.key,
        upperCase: false
    });
},
```

Comment: Actually, I don't need it if I don't want to change group header. But I did try to add the header function at some point and set there break point. The code stopped there 3 times (for those 3 groups described in the question).